# Python SSL Error: Certificate Verify Failed

Tags: python, ssl, network-programming, tls1.2

I need to setup a TLS connection using Python but I'm encountering an SSL certification error.
Here's my code:

```py
import socket
import ssl
import json

from ArgumentParser import Parser

argParser = Parser() # just handles command line arg parsing

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
clientSock = context.wrap_socket(
  sock=clientSock,
  server_hostname=argParser.hostName,
)

clientSock.connect((argParser.hostName, argParser.portNum))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)
```

and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The reason for this can be a lot of different things: wrong setup of the server (like missing intermediate certificates), self-signed certificate in server which is not trusted, something intercepting the TLS connection (local antivirus, corporate firewall), ... . The ways to solve this are thus different though. It is impossible to find out from the information provided what the real problem is (not reproducible, no exact target hostname and environment known) and thus what the appropriate fix would be. But there are a lot a lot of similar questions here.

Answer (score -1):

Please import Valid CA certs in case of prod. However in dev you can use
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

```
import socket
import ssl
import json

from ArgumentParser import Parser

argParser = Parser() # just handles command line arg parsing

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
clientSock = context.wrap_socket(
  sock=clientSock,
  server_hostname=argParser.hostName,
)

clientSock.connect((argParser.hostName, argParser.portNum))
```